# How to loop around a table using java to get the count of particular column with value 1

Tags: java

i have a table  with unique account number and different location id. How do i loop around the table to get the count of number of 1’s in included column using java

```
account   location id  included
123           1               0
123           2               1
123           3               1
```

Comment: What type of table do you mean? Database table? What database? GUI table? What GUI?  HTML or other web-based table? What library are you using? Can you show code?

Answer (score 1):

First  get  a  table
Second  take  account  and  included column put in  a HashaMap or Hashtable
Then  using  get  method,retrieve account number  using  included  column.